# Form submit not working on chrome in Samsung A8 (android)

Tags: android, jquery, html, forms

I am using a simple form to send an email but on my device the click is not firing anything.

Here is my code:

```
            <form class="form-inline"  action="mailto:user@gmail.com?subject=oggetto" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="sr-only">Nome e Cognome</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Nome e Cognome">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="bambini" class="sr-only">Numero bambini</label>
                        <input type="name" name="bambini" class="form-control" id="numBambini" placeholder="Numero di bambini">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block"> 
                   </input>
                </div>

            </form>
```

I tried also with

> the tag button type="submit"

with no luck.

My code is working fine on Chrome desktop but on my samsung device works only with Samsung Internet and not with Chrome (I also got the same with a samsung p20).

Any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Looks more like an issue related to how the phone is handling the `mailto` rather than an actual problem in your code.

Comment: using another browser (internet samsung) is working properly

Comment: One thing to try is give the mailto: link a `target="_top"` and see if that helps.  But in reality, mailto: links are dependent on the browser, and since you can't control every browser that someone might possibly use, your only real option for making it work universally is to set up the email to happen on the server side, and then trigger it with with a POST from the browser (or using AJAX)